# Define date steps in a form or property

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime, orm

I have defined a property that use a `Datetime` type:

```
class myClass
{

/**
 * @Constraints\NotNull
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $date;
...
}
```

I have this property added in a form:

```
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($myClassObject)
            ->add('date')
            ->getForm(); 
        return $this->render('myTemplate', array('detailsForm', $form->createView());
```

and this form is used inside `myTemplate`:

```
        <form method="post">
            {{ form_widget(detailsForm) }}
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
```

but I want to display the time with 5 minutes steps:

```
00 - 05 - 10 - ... - 50 - 55
```

Is there any way to define it as a property constraint or as a field's form definition?

Comment: Do you want only the time or the date and the time?

Comment: @n.1 - Just the minutes in steps.

Comment: But your variable is named `date`?

Comment: @n.1 - My property is named `date`, as you can see.

Comment: Naming it `date` can be misleading since it is not only a date but a `Datetime` object with minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` field type is only for a date, so you have to use `datetime` to display minutes and seconds:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('date', 'datetime', array(
        'minutes' => range(0, 55, 5)
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

The interesting part is the `minutes` options which accept an array of values for the minutes. This option is available for [`datetime`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#minutes) and [`time`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html#minutes) field types.

And I suggest to name your object property `date` if it contains a date only, otherwise `datetime` is a better name.

Comment: Thank you! It works! But `'date'` was just the name of the property, not the type. So I've done: `add('date', 'datetime', array('minutes' => range(0, 55, 5)));`

Comment: Oops, thanks, I'll update my answer so it will correspond exactly to your question.